# File Manager sometimes doesn't find subfolder in documents directory

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have asked this before, but had to reformulate everything so it becomes more understandable.

In my project, I have created a subfolder inside the `documents directory` called `HTML` with the following code:

```
fileprivate func createFolderOnDocumentsDirectoryIfNotExists() {
    let folderName = "HTML"
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if let tDocumentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let filePath =  tDocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(folderName)")
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: filePath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't create document directory")
            }
        }
        print("Document directory is \(filePath)")
    }
}
```

The print statement prints the following:

> Document directory is file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/103869C9-9D46-4595-A370-A93BCD75D495/Documents/HTML

Inside my app's `Bundle` I have a `.css` file for me to use in a `HTML` string to be presented in a `WKWebView`.

As the `.css` file needs to be in the same folder as the `HTML baseURL` , I copy that `.css` file from the `Bundle` to the directory created with the above function, with the following code:

```
fileprivate func copyCSSFileToHTMLFolder() {
    guard let cssURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "swiss", withExtension: "css") else { return }
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if let tDocumentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fp = tDocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("HTML")
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fp.path) {
            let fp2 =  fp.appendingPathComponent(cssURL.lastPathComponent)
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: cssURL.path, toPath: fp2.path)
            } catch {
                print("\nFailed to copy css to HTML folder with error:", error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I could use both in the app's `Bundle` by setting the `HTML baseURL` to the `main.Bundle`, but since I need to present local images inside the `HTML` and not web-linked images, I had to move those into a subfolder in order for me to later copy the desired images into that subfolder, since the `main.Bundle` is read-only and not writable (We cannot save there images).

Now I have a `ViewController` that gets pushed through a `UINavigationController`; inside that pushed `ViewController` I have a `WKWebView` that will present the `HTML`.

I also have a `var markdownString: String? {}` property that once instantiated I convert it to a `HTML` string using the following function:

```
func getHTML(str: String) -> String {
    /*
      the cssImport here points to the previously copied css file as they are on the same folder
    */

    let cssImport = "<head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"swiss.css\"></head>"
    let htmlString = try? Down(markdownString: str).toHTML()    
    return cssImport + htmlString!
}
```

My `WKWebView` is declared with the following code:

```
private lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    // script to fit the content with the screen
    var scriptContent = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"

    let wkuscript = WKUserScript(source: scriptContent, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    let wkucontroller = WKUserContentController()
    wkucontroller.addUserScript(wkuscript)

    let wkwebconfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    wkwebconfig.userContentController = wkucontroller

    let wv = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: wkwebconfig)
    wv.frame.size.height = 1
    return wv
}()
```

Whenever my `markdown String` is set, I convert it to an `HTML` string, then I instantiate the `HTML baseURL` and the I load it into my `webView` with the following code:

```
public var markdownString: String? {
    didSet {
        guard let kPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("HTML", isDirectory: true) else { return }

        guard let str = markdownString else { return }
        let html = getHTML(str: str)

        print("base url:", kPath)

        let fm = FileManager.default

        do {
            let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: kPath.path)
            print("items:", items)
        } catch {
            print("Error:", error)
        }
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: kPath)
    }
}
```

Here's where my problem starts.

The `swiss.css` file is in the following directory:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/103869C9-9D46-4595-A370-A93BCD75D495/Documents/HTML/

The `HTML baseURL` points to the following path:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/103869C9-9D46-4595-A370-A93BCD75D495/Documents/HTML/

As you can see, they're both pointing to the same path.

Sometimes my `HTML` finds the `swiss.css` file, as it prints the `items` in the `do{}catch{}` block, but other times it doesn't find the folder, the `try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: kPath.path)` fires an error catched in the `catch{}` block printing the following:

> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The folder “HTML” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/103869C9-9D46-4595-A370-A93BCD75D495/Documents/HTML, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Folder
>   ), NSUnderlyingError=0x1c044e5e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

This both happens in the simulator and on the real device.

What's causing this issue? Why does it finds the folder sometimes and other times it doesn't, even without rebooting the app, which may reset the `documents directory` path, even though I'm not forcing the path, but instead I'm fetching it as you can see above.

I don't understand this behavior.

**UPDATE**

So I was thinking that reading the `html` string directly might be causing some problems so I changed my `markdown: String?` declaration.

In it, I write the converted markdown string (not an html string) into a file in the same path, called `index.html`.

Now one think different happened -- when I push this view in the first time, it now finds my `swiss.css` file and the `html` file detects it and uses it as expected; so far so good.

**but** when I dismiss this view controller, poping to the parent view controller (pressing the back button) and then try to push it again, the same error (described previously) prompts:

> Failed to write html to file with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “index.html” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C0639153-6BA7-40E7-82CF-25BA4CB4A943/Documents/HTML/index.html, NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c045d850 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Note that some of the paths here are different than the previous, because it is a different launch and it changes, but that's not the problem here because I never store the path and force write it, I always fetch the URLs with the default File Manager fetch,

The updated `markdown` declaration goes by the following:

```
public var markdownString: String? {
    didSet {
        guard let kPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("HTML", isDirectory: true) else { return }

        guard let str = markdownString else { return }
        let html = getHTML(str: str)

        do {
            let writePath = kPath.appendingPathComponent("index.html")
            try html.write(to: writePath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
            webView.loadFileURL(writePath, allowingReadAccessTo: kPath)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to write html to file with error:", error)
            return
        }

        let fm = FileManager.default
        do {
            let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: kPath.path)
            print("items:", items)
        } catch {
            print("Error:", error)
        }   
    }
}
```

Somehow this confused me even more.

Why does it works on the first presentation and then it doesn't?

Comment: May I ask why you have tagged this `css`? How exactly could a CSS expert help you with this question?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You're right; that was a mistake. Fixed

Comment: try replacing " guard let str = markdownString else { return }" This is the only part of your code I find questionable.

Comment: didn't solved the issue replacing that code

Comment: There's no information about when you call the methods `createFolderOnDocumentsDirectoryIfNotExists`, `copyCSSFileToHTMLFolder`, and set `markdownString`.

Comment: @rmaddy you’re right. The `createFolder` is called on the `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunch...` the `markdownString` set is instantiated on a cell click on `didSelectCellForItem...` before pushing the `view controller`

Comment: Are you doing any cleanup of the created files at any point?

Comment: Nope, no deletions occurring :/

Comment: probably is not related but, instead to use: "lazy var webView", might you remove the lazy and initialize WKWebiew in the `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: Can you try replacing

> let writePath = kPath.appendingPathComponent("index.html")

with

> let writePath = kPath.appendingPathComponent("index.html", , isDirectory: false)

Comment: @dequin I'll try

Comment: could at least some of the path be a virtual mount point or something along those lines? I'm thinking this sounds like a race condition where the mount is not setup at all times when you try to access it. I don't know how you would find this out without asking apple engineers though.

Comment: Yes. It could be a race condition somehow. Since I don’t know if this is a OS bug or not I haven’t filled a radar to it , but I’ll do it or post this question in the apple developer forum

Comment: Read the guidelines at the bottom of [this url](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html). I suspect you're violating some assumptions and this is causing trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that it can't write to that file path, which means it doesn't exist. You should confirm this in your markdownString method by adding a check for `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: kPath.path)` before you try to write index.html to the writePath.

Once you confirm that, you need to track the life-cycle of the HTML folder's creation (just keep checking `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: thePath)` until you track down when it's disappearing/not getting created.

From the code you posted, there's no obvious indication why this is happening. It has to be somewhere else in your app.

Answer (score 0):

In your UPDATE section you mention the following error:
`Failed to write html to file with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “index.html” doesn’t exist."`
As far as I understood your issue, index.html should not be a folder but a file.

I have no idea why it treats index.html as folder, but maybe replacing
`let writePath = kPath.appendingPathComponent("index.html")`
with
`let writePath = kPath.appendingPathComponent("index.html", isDirectory: false)`
helps or at least leads to a more specific error message.

Comment: That’s the weird part; even replacing the code it logs the error. I don’t know why it’s happening. I think I’ll move forward and rewrite this code part and take a different approach, and then separately I’ll go deeper to figure it out.